# How to give style to option tag?

Tags: html, css, select

```
<div class="filterPage-arrange">
  <select name="arrangement">
   <option hidden>Arrangement</option>
   <option value="low">Lowest Price</option>
   <option value="high">Highest Price</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

style :

```
.filterPage-arrange>select{
  width: 320px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}
div.filterPage-arrange>select>option{
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  width: 320px;
  height: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

the style for select tag works, but the one for the option tag doesn't. I searched about it and js or something was used in the solutions I saw. but I don't want to use js. is there any other solution for this?

Comment: You cannot style options tag. it is platform-dependent. If you want a customized experience, use - Datalist (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

Comment: Your Answer 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element